# Where is the .idlerc folder for Python IDLE on Mac?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, themes, customization, python-idle

I'm looking for the .idlerc folder for IDLE. My setup is Python 2.7.9 + Mac OSX El Capitan. This folder contains the "config-highlight.cfg" file to apply new custom themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.idlerc` should be in your HOME directory.  The code for reading and writing in the directory is in idlelib/configHandler.py, in the GetUserCfgDir 'method'.  I copied it below, with the useless `self` parameter removed, and the needed imports added.

```
import os, sys

def GetUserCfgDir():
    """Return a filesystem directory for storing user config files.

    Creates it if required.
    """
    cfgDir = '.idlerc'
    userDir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    if userDir != '~': # expanduser() found user home dir
        if not os.path.exists(userDir):
            warn = ('\n Warning: os.path.expanduser("~") points to\n ' +
                    userDir + ',\n but the path does not exist.')
            try:
                print(warn, file=sys.stderr)
            except OSError:
                pass
            userDir = '~'
    if userDir == "~": # still no path to home!
        # traditionally IDLE has defaulted to os.getcwd(), is this adequate?
        userDir = os.getcwd()
    userDir = os.path.join(userDir, cfgDir)
    if not os.path.exists(userDir):
        try:
            os.mkdir(userDir)
        except OSError:
            warn = ('\n Warning: unable to create user config directory\n' +
                    userDir + '\n Check path and permissions.\n Exiting!\n')
            print(warn, file=sys.stderr)
            raise SystemExit
    # TODO continue without userDIr instead of exit
    return userDir

print(GetUserCfgDir())
```

I will consider adding this information to the Preferences dialog.  But I also note that one can add a theme by editing an existing theme in the dialog.  For 2.7.11, 3.4.4, and 3.5.1, IDLE has a new dark theme to start from.  To make editing easier, we plan to add an easy means of changing the default background for all items that use it.